# if I got a List(of t) how to filter out item from a linq 2 sql query?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a **list(of t)** and I got a **iqueryable(of a)**

I want to **filter out** any item from the **iqueryable(of a)** where a.id = t.myotherid

I'm not really sure how to write this query, anyone could help me here?

For now I got this

```
Dim listCie = (From c In db.getListCompany() _
                Where Not rels.Select(Function(a) a.ChildID).Contains(c.ID) _
                  And Not rels.Select(Function(a) a.ParentId).Contains(c.ID) _
                Select c)
```

question is, should I use **.Any** or is there any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim result = From item In queryable _
             Where Not list.Select(Function(x) x.MyOtherId).Contains(item.Id) _
             Select item
```

Comment: no, wont work already tried this since the list contain an object with different proprieties

Comment: Close, but it's not comparing based on the id of the list object only. Need to .Select.Any() off the list for that.

Comment: Fredou: I don't think LINQ to SQL translates `Enumerable.Any`. It just supports `.Contains` for client side collections AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result = From item In queryable _
             Where Not list.Any(Function(t) t.MyOtherID = item.Id) _
             Select item
```

An alternative is to use the `.Intersect()` method.

Comment: Joel: I don't think LINQ to SQL is able to handle `Enumerable.Any()`.

Comment: `List<T>` does not have an `Any` method. It's an extension method coming from `System.Linq.Enumerable` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do can be achieved with a join. You can get some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737929.aspx#selmany12m-2)